# SendTextMessage проблема

Tags: android, sms

В общем есть программа отправки SMS, но на некоторых телефонах SMS отсылаются, а на некоторых нет, в чем может быть проблемма?

```
public void sendSmsMessage(String address, String message) {
    SmsManager SMSMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
    SMSMgr.sendTextMessage(address, null, message, null, null);

}
```

Comment: например, потому что телефон - планшет:) И симкарты у него нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы:

```
//-----------------------------------SMS Manager------------------------------------------------
public void sendSmsMessage(String address, String msg) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    PendingIntent sentPI;
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

    sms.sendTextMessage(address, null, msg, sentPI, null);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Миллион причин, например:

1. Если версия Android у телефона >= KitKat, то приложение не может отсылать сообщения пока не будет назначено как дефолтный обработчик смс сообщений (а сделать это довольно сложно)
2. По хорошему надо резать сообщение с помощью `SMSManager.divideMessage()` и отсылать как мультипартное с помощью `SMSManager.sendMultipartTextMessage()`
3. Возможно банально вырублена смс услуга на уровне оператора
4. Может это планшет без GSM/CDMA модуля

Ну и т.д.

Comment: буду пробовать пункт 2, телефон - Samsung Galaxy S4 Lollipop, и еще один телефон с JellyBean